# Android Loader - handle an arbitrary number of them

Tags: android, sqlite, android-loadermanager

Say I want to run a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT _id FROM my_table WHERE name = user_supplied_name
```

What if the user has supplied an array of names of some arbitrary length, and I need to get the corresponding array of _id numbers from my_table?

Is the correct solution:

a.) supply the WHERE clause similar to:

```
WHERE name = name_1 OR name = name_2 OR name = name_3 ... etc
```

b.) Fire off multiple Loaders for each name query (same format as my first snippet). But then, how to keep track of each Loader when they all have a different ID (as in Loader.getId()). Presumably you'd have to reserve a range of ID numbers (say 10 to 20) to avoid conflict, but then you are limited in the number of names that can be supplied, keep track of which ones are assigned, etc.

c.) some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple loaders would not only be hard to manage but also be inefficient.

Searching for multiple names with one query works just fine, and matches best with what you want to do with the result, so go for it.

---

BTW: you can also use [`IN`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op):

```
SELECT _id FROM my_table WHERE name IN ('name1', 'name2', ...)
```

Comment: Just realised that I don't even need to run this query at all. However, I believe this is a useful answer for anyone who asks the same question.